# memory barrier example of JMM cookbook confusion

Tags: memory-barriers, java-memory-model

I am confused with this compiler insertion of barrier example in the JMM cookbook
http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html

i = u (don't it involve a volatile load from u and normal store into i ? )

j = b (looks to me a Normal load from b and normal store into j )

According to the lookup table in the cookbook, where is the two barrier LoadLoad and LoadStore come from?

Thanks!

///////////////// JSR example ////

volatile int u;

int i,b,j;

i = u; //load u

```
    LoadLoad
    LoadStore
```

j = b; //load b